# download code expalanation in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

can anyone please explain this code

```
if (e.CommandName == "download")
            {
                string filename = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                string path = MapPath("~/Docfiles/" + filename);
                byte[] bts = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "Application/octet-stream");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bts.Length.ToString());
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
                Response.BinaryWrite(bts);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
```

what is command argument, mappath, and also what is this
"Content-Type", "Application/octet-stream"
and also

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bts.Length.ToString());
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
                Response.BinaryWrite(bts);
                Response.Flush();
```

Comment: You can try and google the terms.

Comment: how i find expalantion of this code.. i dont find thats why i posted here

Comment: It's pretty self-explanatory. It's downloading a file when the user clicks a button. The file is in the application root (~/ is shorthand for app root) / DocFiles directory. You usually see this kind of code when a file is generated on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I advise you to use the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/) to search for more information about the objects and methods you wanna know more about. MSDN is a useful network and should be used.

Quoting the MSDN [CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) : "Gets or sets an optional parameter passed to the Command event along with the associated CommandName". It is used to get an parameter that was passed to the command event. In this case, it was the file name.

```
string filename = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
```

The [MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is used to map a specified path to a physical path. Using this you get the real path of the file. For example: "C:\Docfiles\Yourfile.pdf"

```
string path = MapPath("~/Docfiles/" + filename);
```

The [ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, opens a file, reads the content and then closes the file. This return the content of this file as a byte array.

```
byte[] bts = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

The [Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525405%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) object is used to send output to the user from the server.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
```

Response.AddHeader is used to build the header of response that will be sent back to user. We use it to set infos about the data we are sending back to the client.
The "Content-Type" attribute is used to especify what kind of file you are returning to the user.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "Application/octet-stream");
```

The "Content-Length" attribute is used to inform to the browser the size of the the file you are returning.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bts.Length.ToString());
```

The "Content-Disposition" is used to inform the name of the file that will be returned. For example "file1.doc"
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

The "BinaryWrite()" write your file (who, at this moment, is in a byte array format) to the current HTTP output without any character conversion.

```
Response.BinaryWrite(bts);
```

The Flush method sends buffered output immediately.

```
Response.Flush();
```

And, finally, causes the server to stop processing the request and return the current result.

```
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the command is download, most likely from a grid button, then get the name of the file as the argument (these are properties on a button control), and send it to the browser.  This prompts the user to download the file.